# Find limit of volume of n dimensional box in different unit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose we have a n dimensional box with length in each dimension =$50$ $cms$. If we find the volumne where n tends to infinity we get its magnitude as infinity. But if we convert it to meters before finding the volume we get the magnitude to be $0$. So does the box in the limiting case have any volume or not?

Answer (score 1):

So you are looking at the sequence $a_n = (50 \text{cm})^n$.  But the units for $a_n$ is $\text{cm}^n$, and so $a_n$ and $a_m$ cannot be compared for $m \ne n$.  So asking what the limit is makes no sense.

(To put it another way, what would the units for the limit be?  $\text{cm}^\infty$ makes no sense.)